# Parse user list from Github's Json response

Tags: android, json, github

So I'm parsing Github user array using *AsyncHttpClient* library. And the result of this parsing is String object with Json response (its still a draft):

```
private String getResponse()
{
    AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
    params.put("since","0");
    client.get("https://api.github.com/users", params,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                                      Throwable arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {

                    try {
                        String content = new String(arg2, "UTF-8");
                        //content is json response that can be parsed.
                        response = content;
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    if (response.isEmpty())
        return "Users not found";
    else
        return response;
}
```

The question is how do I parse from this response? I mean, how do you do this when you don't know the structure of Github user api? 
I'm trying to solve this smth like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> parseResponse (String response)
{

    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject nameObject = reader.getJSONObject("????"); //I don't know 
           //how that object is called since no idea about structure!
        name = nameObject.getString("name");

        userList.add(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userList;
}
```

And how to iterate this properly to get every user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But you do know the structure of the response. It's a JSONArray. That is why you cannot search any user as a JSONObject using a String with the object name. You have to take another approach.

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted this question. To get proper approach or solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the login from every user on the response, you have to iterate over the JSONArray, like this:

```
try {
    JSONArray readerArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int i=0;i<readerArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject userObject = (JSONObject) readerArray.get(i);
        String login = userObject.getString("login");
        //add login to your ArrayList here
    }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Where `result` is a String with your `Json` response.

Answer (score 3):

Just navigate to `https://api.github.com/users` in your browser and take a look.

**Example:**

```
[
  {
    "login": "",
    "id": 0,
    "avatar_url": "",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "",
    "html_url": "",
    "followers_url": "",
    "following_url": "",
    "gists_url": "",
    "starred_url": "",
    "subscriptions_url": "",
    "organizations_url": "",
    "repos_url": "",
    "events_url": "",
    "received_events_url": "",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  {...}
]
```

You can see from the `[]` that the top-level element is a JSONArray. So you need to get this array, and then access the JSONObject at each index.

```
JSONArray users = new JSONArray(response);
for(int i=0; i<users.length(); i++){
    JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
    String login = user.getString("login");
}
```

Comment: but still it doesn't answer the question entirely. How to get _login_ of each user and add to ArrayList?

Comment: @Selvin glad you have sarcasm. I wouldn't have posted this if I found answer to this question in github documentation. You don't realize that not all users of this community are pros. Newbies exist.
Since when stackoverflow became jerkoverflow?

Comment: *jerkoverflow* :D ... but without using google for initial search it will became duplicatesoverflow